# Trying to correctly generate matrices for cascaded shadow maps

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, shadow

I am trying to implement cascaded shadow maps in OpenGL, but I am having trouble generating the view and projection matrices. Here is my code:

```
        glm::mat4 lightViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0), glm::normalize(direction), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

        glm::vec4 min(INFINITY);
        glm::vec4 max(-INFINITY);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            glm::vec4 lightSpaceCorner = lightViewMatrix * frustumCornersWorldSpace[i];

            min = glm::min(min, lightSpaceCorner);
            max = glm::max(max, lightSpaceCorner);
        }

        glm::mat4 ortho = glm::ortho(min.x, max.x, min.y, max.y, min.z, max.z);

        mMatrices[cascade] = ortho * lightViewMatrix ;
```

The resulting shadow map is cut off at certain angles, which leads me to believe that the either the view or projection matrix is incorrectly configured.

If anyone knows the answer, it would be a huge help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! Turns out the issue wasn't with the matrices, but the depth value I was using to decide which cascade I should use. I was using gl_FragCoord.z, thinking it was in clip space.